# Splitting single observation into multiple observations

Tags: sas

I have the following SAS data set:

```
data mydata;
   LENGTH id 4.0 num 4.0 A $ 4. B $ 8. C $ 20.;
   input id num A $ B $ C $;
   datalines;
1 1 x yy zzzzz
2 1 x yy zzzzz
3 2 xq yyqq zzzzzqqqqq
4 1 x yy zzzzz
5 3 xqw yyqqww zzzzzqqqqqwwwww
6 1 x yy zzzzz
7 4 xqwe yyqqwwee zzzzzqqqqqwwwwweeeee
;
```

which looks like

```
mydata
-------------------
id num A B C
1  1   x yy zzzzz
2  1   x yy zzzzz
3  2   xq yyqq zzzzzqqqqq
4  1   x yy zzzzz
5  3   xqw yyqqww zzzzzqqqqqwwwww
6  1   x yy zzzzz
7  4   xqwe yyqqwwee zzzzzqqqqqwwwwweeeee
```

The problem is that each of the observations where num > 1 actually contains data for multiple "observations" and I would like to split it up using some logic in SAS. Here's an example for what I want to get:

```
mydatawanted
-------------------
id num A B C
1  1   x yy zzzzz
2  1   x yy zzzzz
3  1   x yy zzzzz
3  1   q qq qqqqq
4  1   x yy zzzzz
5  1   x yy zzzzz
5  1   q qq qqqqq
5  1   w ww wwwww
6  1   x yy zzzzz
7  1   x yy zzzzz
7  1   q qq qqqqq
7  1   w ww wwwww
7  1   e ee eeeee
```

Basically, if num > 1 I want to take the substring of each variable depending on its length, for each item, and then output those as new observations with num = 1. Here is what I have tried to code so far:

```
data mydata2(drop=i _:);
    set mydata; /*use the data from the original data set */
    _temp_id = id; /*create temp variables from the currently read observation */
    _temp_num = num;
    _temp_A = A;
    _temp_B = B;
    _temp_C = C;
    if (_temp_num > 1) THEN /* if num in current record > 1 then split them up */
        do i = 1 to _temp_num;
            id = _temp_id; /* keep id the same */
            num = 1; /* set num to 1 for each new observation */
            A = substr(_temp_A,i,i); /*split the string by 1s */
            B = substr(_temp_B,1 + 2 * (i - 1),i * 2); /*split the string by 2s */
            C = substr(_temp_C,1 + 5 * (i - 1),i * 5); /*split the string by 5s */
            OUTPUT; /* output this new observation with the changes */
        end;
    else OUTPUT; /* if num == 1 then output without any changes */
run;
```

However it doesn't work as I wanted it to (I put in some comments to show what I thought was happening at each step). It actually produces the following result:

```
mydata2
-------------------
id num A B C
1  1   x yy zzzzz
2  1   x yy zzzzz
3  1   x yy zzzzz
3  1   q qq qqqqq
4  1   x yy zzzzz
5  1   x yy zzzzz
5  1   qw qqww qqqqqwwwww
5  1   w ww wwwww
6  1   x yy zzzzz
7  1   x yy zzzzz
7  1   qw qqww qqqqqwwwww
7  1   we wwee wwwwweeeee
7  1   e ee eeeee
```

This mydata2 result isn't the same as mydatawanted. The lines where num = 1 are fine but when num > 1 the output records are much different from what I want. The total number of records are correct though. I'm not really sure what is happening, since this is the first time I tried any complicated SAS logic like this, but I would appreciate any help in either fixing my code or accomplishing what I want to do using any alternate methods. Thank you!

edit: **I fixed a problem with my original input mydata data statement** and updated the question.

Comment: First thin gI'd do is go back to whomever gave you this data and give them a good talking to.  This is a terrible way to store data.

Comment: Haha, I agree! I believe they did it to try and save space somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substrings are incorrect.  Substr takes the arguments `(original string, start, length)`, not `(original string, start, ending position)`.  So `length` should be `1,2,5` not `i,i*2,i*5`.

```
        A = substr(_temp_A,i,1); /*split the string by 1s */
        B = substr(_temp_B,1 + 2 * (i - 1),2); /*split the string by 2s */
        C = substr(_temp_C,1 + 5 * (i - 1),5); /*split the string by 5s */
```

Comment: I'd also recommend for simplicity of code removing the `if` and simply doing this for _every_ row.  If i=1 then it doesn't do anything, but that block of code doesn't exactly take very long.  Unless you're parsing tens of millions of records the additional time won't be significant, but the code simplicity will make this easier to maintain.

Comment: D'oh, on one hand I'm sorry for the simple mistake, but on the other hand I'm really glad it wasn't something too complicated. This fixed it perfectly. By the way, good point on the if, I actually am processing a lot of records (not sure if tens of millions, but maybe around 1 million ?) but you're right it probably won't affect the speed much. Also, thanks again for the help Joe!